# SetCookie возвращает true, но не отображается в браузере

Tags: php, cookie

Сегодня столкнулся с очень странной проблемой. Может, заработался, но у меня возникла очень непонятная проблема с куками. Суть в том, что когда я записываю куки, мне в ответ выдаётся true, то есть вроде как они записываются. Однако после перезагрузки страницы их по-прежнему не видно. Перерыл гугл, но не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос. Вот часть кода:

```
public function signup() {
    if($this->checkEmail()) {
        $this->hash = $this->hash();
        if($this->addNewUser()) {
            if($this->set_cookie()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private function set_cookie() {
    $user_id = $this->selectUser();
    $secret = "secretword";
    $signature = sha1($user_id.$secret);
    $cookie_id = $user_id."|".$signature;
    return setcookie("ST_ID", $cookie_id, time()+5184000, "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."");
}
```

Все функции работают нормально, то есть я успешно дохожу до `$this->set_cookie()`. `$cookie_id` тоже отображается верно. У кого есть какие идеи?

P.S. Пробовал вынести запись куков из тела функции. Не помогло. (((

Answer (score 1):

Пятиминутный мастер-класс по оформлению кода:

```
public function signup() {
    if (!$this->checkEmail()) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->hash = $this->hash();
    return $this->addNewUser() && $this->set_cookie();
}
```

Comment: Да, полезно, но не совсем то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался, в чём дело. Странно, конечно, немного. Нужно прописать 4 аргумента вместо 5. Это, видимо, особенность localhost.